# Applying the patch AC-3022.patch on magento 2.4.3-p1 gives deprecated error

Tags: magento2

I have applied a patch AC-3022.patch in magento 2.4.3-p1, but it gives error: Patch is deprecated

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/notes/security-patches/2-4-3-p1.html?lang=en
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjUtS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjUtS.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqrad.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqrad.png

Why is the patch deprecated?

Applied patch using following commands in magento root directory -
step 1 - composer require magento/quality-patches
step 2 ./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply AC-3022

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the compatibility of your store version with the patch requirements; please specify the following things:

- What's your Magento version
- PHP version
- As of Magento 2.4.4, the system requirement has been changed from PHP7.4 to PHP8.1

So, carefully upgrade the PHP version and apply the patch again.